# Why doesn't jQuery's deep copy not copy descriptive properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery

While learning about [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), I was trying it for deep cloned objects. Consider the following snippet,

```js
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key', {
  get: () => {return key},
  set: (value) => {
          if (typeof(value) == 'number'){
              key = value;
          }
       }
});

obj.key = 54;
console.log(obj.key);                 // Output: 54
obj.key = ['a', 'b'];
console.log(obj.key);                 // Output: 54

var clone = $.extend(true, {}, obj);

clone.key = 44;
console.log(obj.key, clone.key);      // Output: 54 44
clone.key = 'hello';
console.log(clone.key);               // Output: hello
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why does the clone created by jQuery not maintain the original getters and setters from the object. If I do require this functionality, how can I get deeply cloned objects to have the same getters and setters as their parents?

Comment: "Why?": probably because no-one has extended the jQuery `$.exfend` implementation to do so; or maybe because of performance concerns for the simpler cases? You could submit a PR.

Comment: jQuery doesn't use ES2015 for this. There's not `create` or `assign`, just simple loops that iterate recursively, creating a deep clone. These loops unfortunately doesn't clone getters and setters, just enumerable properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a property using `Object.defineProperty`, with a descriptor for `set`, you add an event for the value to be changed. This event is associated with the reference of object.

When you use `$.extend`, what it does is, copy its value.

Following is the partial code of `$.extend`

```js
for (; i < length; i++) {

  // Only deal with non-null/undefined values
  if ((options = arguments[i]) != null) {

    // Extend the base object
    for (name in options) {
      src = target[name];
      copy = options[name];
```

As you see, only the value is copied. The reason why the descriptor is not copied can be that, the intention of having a descriptor would be specific to that object alone and not to its child.

This behavior is also shared by `Object.assign`

```js
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key', {
  get: () => {
    return key
  },
  set: (value) => {
    if (typeof(value) == 'number') {
      key = value;
    }
  }
});

obj.key = 54;
console.log(obj.key); // Output: 54
obj.key = ['a', 'b'];
console.log(obj.key); // Output: 54

var clone = Object.assign({}, obj)

clone.key = 44;
console.log(obj.key, clone.key); // Output: 54 44
clone.key = 'hello';
console.log(clone.key); // Output: hello
```

Comment: **Note:** Above answer is based on my understanding and can be incorrect. If you feel anything is *incorrect/not required* please comment along with you vote. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the scope of the functions.
You are not able to clone the scope and to avoid problems they decided to omit functions while cloning.

But i am not sure about that.